# Responding to doctoral offer letters - What questions to ask?

Tags: graduate-admissions

'Tis this season of doctoral offer letters. I have been accepted to a few of the institutions I have applied for thankfully and now I want to ask the deans questions about their offer letters. For context, these are U.S. and Australian mathematics doctoral programs. A few I thought of are:

1. Is there a healthcare plan included in the offer letter? Subsidized by the institution?
2. How many hours do other students spend on their TA duties? How many are formally requested?
3. What is the average housing price of the area?
4. Does the department have a tea time? Regular seminars?
5. Does the department have regular funding to send students to conferences such as the Joint Math Meetings?
6. What is the passing rate of students for Quals on their first try?

I should also note that, unfortunately, I have not heard back from my top-pick school where there is a professor that I very much want to work with. The schools I have been accepted to do not seemingly have a person that does the research I am currently interested in. Can I ask how they would see my future pursuing research in XYZ at that institution? i.e, advice on who to work with there to do that sort of work.

Comment: This question is too broad.  Please narrow it.  Questions that have many valid answers do not work with this site.

Comment: Where else may I ask this "broad" question?

Comment: Many of these questions are inappropriate to ask a dean.  Healthcare and housing information can be found on the internet.  Deans are responsible for overall strategy, not practical details.  Ask current students and alumni about quality of life.  Ask about what happens to students after they leave.

Comment: I assume this is UK, correct?

Comment: Buffy, I apologize for not mentioning that. These are U.S.A and Australian programs.

Comment: Most of this information can be found at the website for the program or university. Start there - asking these questions before trying to answer them yourself comes off as a bit rude to me. Several of them are things you probably should have researched before even applying.

Comment: I had found some of the information on their respective website. I'm not sure why it is assumed that an attempt to answer them myself before asking was not done. Since I am a first generation student this whole process was new so I apologize if these were questions I should have asked beforehand. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I think here you want to figure out who is the director of the graduate program (or even the program assistant) and ask these questions of that person, rather than the dean.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I check and I misused the title. The persons I have been in contact with are the graduate directors of the programs. Not the dean as I now understand to be a higher position.